# Какой тип индекса выбрать для поля в POSTGRES?

Tags: postgresql, индексы

При создании базы данных в Postgres над полем с номерами телефонов (в поле нет плюсов и скобок, но тип данных было решено использовать тестовое (text)) был создан индекс btree. Но в ходе использования было решено создать индексирование для полнотекстового поиска. Btree нормально справляется с использованием поискового оператора like вот в таком случае: '792886273%', но в случае когда мы вначале текса используем символ %, поиск работает очень долго ('%8627315'). Вопрос: какой тип индекса посоветуете использовать в таком случае? Спасибо

Comment: Сделайте поле для хранения номера в обратном порядке и проиндексируйте его обычным образом. Тогда такой поиск можно преобразовать в поиск по полю с обратным порядком цифр `5137268%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так для [полнотекстового поиска](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) или для `like '%foo'`? Что есть разные вещи.

btree, конечно, никак не годится для `like '%foo'`. Невозможно эффективно пройти по дереву, если мы не знаем, куда свернуть на первой же развилке.

`like '%foo'` или `like '%foo%'` могут быть ускорены с помощью триграммного поиска, реализованного расширением [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.40.8) с GIN либо GIST индексом

```
create extension pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON test_trgm USING GIST (t gist_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON test_trgm USING GIN (t gin_trgm_ops);
```

Comment: Тогда индекс btree удалить? Либо одно другому не мешает?

Comment: Вы можете хоть полностью одинаковые индексы сделать (только с разными именами). Смысла в этом только не так уж много, а стоимость есть. Какие нужны индексы - определяется запросами.